# how do electrons make a metal coil (lightbulb, incandescent, LED, etc.) light up?

Tags: amplifier

No eBook or tutorial says how thia exactly works. So in practice, I put any 9V battery to a breadboard, connect a resistor and an LED, and it just makes it "go on", but how?

Comment: No e-book or tutorial explains LEDs? You did not [look very hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode).  Also [incandescent light bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_bulb) "This question does not show any research effort", I'm afraid. And why the amplifier tag?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  In the title you mention a "coil", then explicitly mention "lightbulb" (whatever that means), incandescent, and LED.  LEDs don't have "metal coils", so your question can't be answered.  There are lots of ways to use electricity to make light.  Which are you asking about?  *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is overly broad, so I am going to give you a broad answer.

Atoms will emit energy (a.k.a., light) when electrons in the atom go from a higher orbit to a lower orbit.  When an atom absorbs energy, an electron is moved from a lower orbit to a higher one.  To make an atom emit light, you add energy to force the electrons into a higher orbit.  When the electron decays back into the lower orbit it will emit light.  This is the fundamental process that works in all forms of light.  The difference between types of lights is how the electrons are put into the higher orbits.

Incandescent Lamps:  An electrical current is ran through the filament, heating it up.  That heat is energy, and when an atom absorbs the heat energy electrons are bumped into a higher orbit.  When it decays, you get light.

Florescent Lamps:  An electrical current is ran through a gas (usually containing Mercury vapors and other things). This current directly bumps the electrons into a higher orbit, not due to heat.  Unfortunately, this process creates ultraviolet light and not visible light.  The inside surface of the lamp is coated with various types of phosphorous.  This absorbs the UV light, bumping those electrons up.  When the phosphor electrons decay, it emits visible light.  The types of phosphors will determine if you get a cool white, warm white, or other color of light.

LED:  An electrical current flows through the semiconductor material and bumps the electrons up, etc.  The type of material used will determine the color of the LED.  Most white LED's use a blue or UV LED that then causes some phosphors to emit white light-- like the Florescent lamps do.

I should mention lasers at this point, at least briefly.  All lights up to this point mainly focus on bumping the electron's orbit up, but let the electron decay naturally.  Lasers have a lot of stuff in a laser that works on controlling how the electron decays to a lower orbit.  By carefully controlling the decay, a laser gets a very intense and precise beam of coherent light.

That's about it.  Going into any more detail would require getting into Quantum Physics-- something that nobody here wants me to do.  But seriously, if this is something that you really want to learn the I suggest going into some advanced science courses at the local university.

Comment: I want to learn more, but I am noy attending any schools, sorry.